# Are there masterballs in Pokemon go yet?

Tags: pokemon-go

Are there masterballs in pokemon go? Because you don't get any even on highest lvl.

Comment: Masterballs will probably be an event driven reward with a very limited number available to each player. We can't have people running around picking them up at every Pokestop, having 50 and then tossing them at CP10 pidgeys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://comicbook.com/2016/07/19/yes-there-are-master-balls-in-pokemon-go/) source. Masterballs are in the game's files, but not currently obtainable. They may be implemented in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Reference to them is found in the [data dump](https://gist.github.com/KazWolfe/68e10ebf1ed41ae1ae6de2350d5de884), but no one has seen them yet. Most likely they will be awarded at even higher level than the current cap.